# How to build this auto-growing WPF window?

Tags: .net, wpf

I'm struggling with how to build this window in WPF.

The window has a Text Block whose contents are not known at design time.  The Window should grow vertically to make the entire Text Block visible

I've tried a hierarchy similar to:

```
Window (auto height)
    Stack Panel (vertical orientation)
        Text Block
        Check Box
        Grid (for precise positioning of the buttons)
            Button 1
            Button 2
```

Is this a reasonable hierarchy?  Is there a better way to build this?

[image: Desired Window]

Comment: On a quick glance, that looks like it should work as long as the TextBlock is configured to size correctly to its contents. You probably want to specify the maximum width too. Have you tried this and it didn't work or are you still just trying to figure out the general layout?

Comment: I'll try it again.  It's not currently work BUT I didn't want to spend any more cycles on this if it's an unsound approach.  Seems like the approach is OK

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are doing should work fine. You will want to make sure that you use the [SizeToContent Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.sizetocontent.aspx) on your parent Window.
Something like this:

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"  Width="525" SizeToContent="Height">
    <Grid Height="auto" >
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
            <TextBlock Name="tb1" TextAlignment="Justify" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" />
            <Grid Height="30">
                <CheckBox VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="Random">Random CheckBox</CheckBox>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Height="auto">
                <Button Name="button1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,80,0" Width="70" Height="30" Click="button1_Click" />
                <Button Name="Button2" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  Width="70" Height="30" Click="Button2_Click" />
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**CodeBehind"

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        tb1.Text += "TextBlock with contentes set at run-time. " + 
                     "This text block should grow in height as necessary, " + 
                     "and push the other controls down.  The window itself " +
                     "should grow to \n\n Another paragraph\n";
    }
```

Comment: Thanks!  This helped me modify my window as desired.  +1, answer

Answer (score 0):

Looks ok to me, assuming you want the button controls to sit just under the text box, stack panels don't automatically fill parent controls. have you tried this layout yet and run into problems or is this a hypothetical question?